# Empty recyclerview in android Fragment

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-fragmentactivity

**New to android development, hardly a month, don't judge me**

This following piece of code is not working when using inside a fragment, but working when using activity

It is showing empty, while instead it should show the list of students as per the layout in the recyclerview, basically we are getting list of students from the api and then showing the list of students in the recyclerview list

```
public class MyFragement extends Fragment {

private FragmentAppBinding binding;
private Context context;

public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater,
                         ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    binding = FragmentAppBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false);
    View root = binding.getRoot();
    context = container.getContext();

    binding = FragmentAppBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
//        setContentView(binding.getRoot());

    String url = "https://server.com/users/api.json";

    ArrayList<FetchStudentModel> FetchStudentModelArrayList = new ArrayList<>();

    StringRequest request = new StringRequest(url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {

            try {

                JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(response);

                JSONObject checkLastUpdate = jsonArray.getJSONObject(0);

                for (int i = 1; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {

                    JSONObject singleStudent = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                    int id = singleStudent.getInt("id");
                    String name = singleStudent.getString("student_name");

                    FetchStudentModel FetchStudentModel = new FetchStudentModel(id, name);
                    FetchStudentModelArrayList.add(FetchStudentModel);

                }

                StudentAdapter studentAdapter = new StudentAdapter(FetchStudentModelArrayList, context);
                LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(context);
                binding.studentsRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
                binding.studentsRecyclerView.setAdapter(StudentAdapter);

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }

        }
    },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Something went wrong" + error.getMessage().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });

    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context);
    requestQueue.add(request);

    return root;
}

@Override
public void onDestroyView() {
    super.onDestroyView();
    // someone suggested on stackoverflow, didn't work
    binding.studentsRecyclerView.setAdapter(null);
    binding = null;

}
```

}

Comment: check the onResponse response, could be empty

Comment: Do you get an error? Did you add the internet permission?

Comment: @Zain yup, fixed permission issue

Comment: @janithcooray how to do that, not able to debug apps, I'm a hardcore web dev

Comment: `Log.v("TESTING", response );` , then view it from the `Logcat` and filter tag `TESTING`. Log.v = verbose , Log.e = error , Log.i = info.

Comment: @janithcooray it is fetching data, that means something is wrong with my logic and that is why it now showing data in recyclerview

Comment: So 'FetchStudentModelArrayList ' contains the expected data when given to the RecyclerViewAdapter? Can you also show the code of your RecycleViewAdapter?